# Embedded typedefs . Huge Linker Error

Tags: c++, typedef

My class currently looks like this

```
    class Hist
    {
    private:
    typedef boost::tuple<double,double,double> tuple;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<tuple> shared_tuple;
    typedef std::vector<shared_tuple> tuple_vector;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<tuple_vector> shared_tuple_vector;


    typedef std::map<int,shared_tuple_vector> inner_map;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<inner_map> shared_inner_map;

    static std::map<std::string, shared_inner_map> stat_History_base;
    static bool CheckStatus(std::string symb );
    };
```

and then I have this method  which is causing a very very huge linker error.

```
 bool Hist::CheckStatus(std::string symb )
{

    std::map<std::string,Hist::shared_inner_map>::iterator found =  stat_History_base.find(symb);
    if(found != stat_History_base.end())
    {
        //Symbol does exist
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The folks of Stack Overflow are very good at reading huge linker errors.

Comment: My bet is `stat_History_base` not being defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the problem is that you are not providing a *definition* for your static member variable `stat_History_base`.

You should add this to the global namespace:

```
std::map<std::string, BaseHistory::shared_inner_map_def> 
BaseHistory::stat_History_base;
```

Notice, that you have to make the `shared_inner_map_def` public in order for it to be accessible from external code (in your code it is currently being declared as `private`).

Also:

> Initially it was working fine until i replaced a std::list with a vector

It is hard to believe that this is indeed the case, since the problem with your code is that it lacked a definition for a static data member.